# ASP.NET FileUpload failure

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, maxrequestlength

Trying to upload a large file (20MB), I set the maxRequestLength to a high enough level (and the expiration time too) in the httpRuntime entry of web.config. The Event Log stopped reporting that the post size exceeds allowed limits, but I still get the same behavior in the browser (IE or FF): "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading." I'm using VS2008 and the built-in web server, not IIS. I've read the Q&A on this topic and even put in the check for the exception (IsMaxRequestExceededEexception) in the application global handler. This was referenced in another StackOverflow thread about this topic. Anyone had anything similar, have any ideas?

Thanks,
 Bob

Answer (score 1):

Not come accross this myself with the built in server, however  you could try increasing the time out  too in the web.config file.

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="****" maxRequestLength="****" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out my problem. I put the  entry into the wrong web.config file -- I have two web apps in the same VS solution. doh!

Answer (score -1):

Http uploads are notoriously unreliable. You should look into some other options that utilize Flash or Silverlight for file uploads.